# How to trigger manual entry event while prefilling data in Angular JS (1.6) powered website

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Need to prefill the data and make sure that it passes validation. Currently the validation is triggered when the user manually enters the data.

Comment: Hi @vanamalli. Can you provide some more detail and possibly some code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @swatsonpicken The requirement is to automatically fill the form in below link  https://new.camsonline.com/Investors/Statements/Consolidated-Account-Statement

Answer (score 1):

We're able to achieve the result with below code.

```
     const elem = document.getElementById('mat-input-0'); 
     elem.value = 'smtomymail@gmail.com'; 
     elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); 
     elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); 

     const elem1 = document.getElementById('mat-input-2'); 
     elem1.value = 'Password123'; 
     elem1.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); 
     elem1.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

     const elem2 = document.getElementById('mat-input-3');
     elem2.value = 'Password123'; 
     elem2.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); 
     elem2.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```